# Android : GLSurfaceView sometimes crashes when activity is closed

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

in 9 months of working on my project I've only had this bug 2 or 3 times, so I would say its very rare but I would still like to know what could be causing it.

when I close my activity (by pressing on home) the activity sometimes crashes and send me back the following stack

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2764): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 47
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2764): java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2764):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1077)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2764):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.swap(GLSurfaceView.java:1035)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2764):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1333)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2764):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
```

It seems to be a error coming from the core GLSurfaceView code rather than my own code.

any ideas ?

Comment: I comment as I don't have an answer.  I've also seen this but extremely rarely.  Currently my openGL app has over 50,000 downloads yet I've only seen this once.  I'm just saying its out there and its not our fault!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have also been trying to identify the root cause for this exception, and a related one: EGL_BAD_ALLOC. I'll update this question if I can find anything, particularly whether there is something I can do from my code to prevent this happening.